# nodejs loopback api is not running while trying to run in pm2

Tags: express, pm2, loopback

My pm2 ecosystem.config.js configuration like below:
 HGBackend is not running. Others are running in pm2

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [
    {
     name      : "HGBackend",
     cwd       : "hgbackend/server",
     script    : "config.json"
    },
    {
    name       : "HGBlockchain",
    cwd        : "hgblockchain/localgrammes",
    script     : "index.js"
   // args       : "start:staging"
   // instances  : 4,
   // exec_mode  : "cluster"
  },
  {
    name   : "HGWeb",
    cwd    : "hgweb/src/server",
    script : "server.js",
    description: ""
  }

]}
```

All are working except HGBackend. HGBackend is loopback api. Others are react and express api.
What will be the cause for not running HGBackend? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

For the `HGWeb` and `HGBlockchain` applications, you are executing the relevant `server.js` in the `script` configuration. For the `HGBackend` you are passing the `config.json` as the `script`. For `Loopback` you also need to execute the `server.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have corrected is. Actually problem in fatasource.json file. Thanks